# How to initialize Django model fields whose loading was deferred?

Tags: python, django

I can overload the Model's `__init__` to change the initialization behavior. But how to do the same when some of the model field loading are deferred? How do I run the initialization logic, which depends on the field values, when that fields are loaded later? Is there something similar to `def clean_fieldname(self)` that is called when the field is loaded later?

Comment: Normally deferred does not matter, since these fields are *lazily* loaded when necessary. However normally it is *not* advisable to override the `__init__`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the initialization logic depends on the field values, so how can I hook into that lazy loading?

Comment: but normally initialization logic should not depend on the fields. A model is not supposed to be an "active" component, more something that (temporary) stores data, makes calculations, persists calculations, etc. As is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model): "*Rather than overriding __init__, try using one of these approaches: (...)*"

Comment: How so? The variables contains the state handled by algorithms of imperative programming, it's expected a object's method requires access to its encapsulated state. In fact Models are expected to be active components, they are domain entities as stated by [django's design philosofies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/misc/design-philosophies/#include-all-relevant-domain-logic): _Models should encapsulate every aspect of an “object,” following Martin Fowler’s Active Record design pattern._

Comment: Of course, but you seem to "inject" extra state into it. A domain object stores as state what it persists. So that is what you retrieve, and store in the database, otherwise it means that if you save an object in the database, and later retrieve it again, it has a different state. Now except for some persistence tools like databases, often a webserver should be as stateless as possible: https://nordicapis.com/defining-stateful-vs-stateless-web-services/#statelesswebservices especially since running systems with several threats, servers, etc. would make the outcome unpredictable.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add more attributes which are derived from the ones stored in database thus does not need to be stored too. [Active Record](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) encapsulates the _needed_ database access to retrieve persisted state, it's not mandatory all state be persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one can override [Model.refresh_from_db()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) to hook into fields lazy loading. At the model class creation time, each field replace themselves with a data descriptor, that descriptors' `__get__()` does the lazy loading when the field is not present in the model instance's `__dict__`, it will call `Model.refresh_from_db(fields=[fieldname])` where `fieldname` is the field that is being acessed.